# WP Как делать фильтрацию полей комментариев только нужной формы?

Tags: wordpress, валидация

Есть сайт на `WordPress` в котором на разных типах записи подключаються разные формы оставления комментариев.
Вариант 1 `<?php get_template_part('template-parts/write-review-block'); ?>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вариант 2 `<?php get_template_part('template-parts/write-review-reply-block'); ?>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку валидацию полей и функцию отправки комментариев (как выяснилось) нельзя держать в темлейтах, то они содержаться в `functions.php` и имеют вид

```
// 2. Validation
add_filter('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_verify_comment');
function custom_verify_comment($commentdata)
{


    if (empty($_POST['rating_product'])) {
        wp_die('Please select a product rating!');
    }

    if (empty($_POST['rating_service'])) {
        wp_die('Please select a service rating!');
    }

    // Проверка Nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
        wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
    }

    return $commentdata;
}


// 3. Saving Fields for block Comments
add_action('comment_post', 'custom_save_comment_field_data', 10, 3 );
function custom_save_comment_field_data($comment_id, $comment_approved, $commentdata)
{
    $comment = get_comment($comment_id);


    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();


    $title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['comment_title']);
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'comment_title', $title);

    $rating_product_value = intval($_POST['rating_product']);
    $rating_service_value = intval($_POST['rating_service']);
    $rating_value = floatval($_POST['rating']);

    $comment_approved = '1';

    add_rating_to_table($comment_id, $user_id, $post_id, $rating_product_value, $rating_service_value, $rating_value, $comment_approved);


    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

        $overrides = [ 'test_form' => false ];

        /// file_upload
        $file_upload_name = $post_id . '_file_' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name']; // Генерируем новое имя файла
        $_FILES['file_upload']['name'] = $file_upload_name; // Устанавливаем новое имя файла
        $upload1 = media_handle_upload( 'file_upload', $post_id, [], $overrides );

        /// file_proof
        $file_proof_name = $post_id . '_proof_' . $_FILES['file_proof']['name']; // Генерируем новое имя файла
        $_FILES['file_proof']['name'] = $file_proof_name; // Устанавливаем новое имя файла
        $upload2 = media_handle_upload( 'file_proof', $post_id, [], $overrides );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $upload1 ) ) {
            add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'file_upload_url', wp_get_attachment_url( $upload1 ) );
        }

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $upload2 ) ) {
            add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'file_proof_url', wp_get_attachment_url( $upload2 ) );
        }
    }


    $checkbox_confirm = isset($_POST['checkbox_confirm']) ? true : false;
    add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'checkbox_confirm', $checkbox_confirm);

}
```

Вопрос - Как разделить логику валидации и отправки данных форм ? К примеру, если для 1 Варианта обязательными к выбору есть поля проставления 2-х рейтингов, то у второй формы их нету, но при попытке отправить комментарь с её помощу валидатор будет ругаться на незаполненность этих полей и не дает отправить форму (где этих полей нету). Как это вылечить, подскажите, пожалуйста ?

```
if (empty($_POST['rating_product'])) {
     wp_die('Please select a product rating!');
}

if (empty($_POST['rating_service'])) {
     wp_die('Please select a service rating!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел правильный ответ. Может кому пригодиться. Необходимо в функции валидации разграничивать валидацию полей по шаблонам. Это выглядит так

```
add_filter('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_verify_comment');
function custom_verify_comment($commentdata)
{

    $is_review_template = is_page_template('template-parts/write-review-block.php');
    $is_reply_template = is_page_template('template-parts/write-review-reply-block.php');


    if ($is_review_template) {

        if (empty($_POST['rating_product'])) {
            wp_die('Please select a product rating!');
        }

        if (empty($_POST['rating_service'])) {
            wp_die('Please select a service rating!');
        }

        // Проверка Nonce
        if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
            wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
        }

    }

    if($is_reply_template){
        // Проверка Nonce
        if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
            wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
        }
    }
    
    return $commentdata;
}
```